# Multilevel menu from database records

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with PHP. I have a multilevel css menu that works fine, but now I want to generate according to the records from a database.

**The menu Code:**

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4 - 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the database every record has a field called **main_manu** which makes it a main link if the value of this field is **Yes**, and if the value is **No** then it has another field (**sub_menu**) which says the parent menu in which this link should be placed.! See the screenshot.
[DB Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l4ii.png)

SO, now I don't know how to do the php piece that will get the records and if the value of the main_menu is yes, it will create a top level menu, and if the value of **main_menu** is no, it will create a sub level menu according to the value of **sub_menu** field.

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

This is the code I have so far and it works. It would be nice if I could use a single query instead of multiple nested queries.

```
<div id='page-wrap'>
    <ul class='dropdown'>
<?

$sql_menu = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE visible = '1' and main_menu='yes' ";
$result_menu = mysql_query($sql_menu); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_menu))
 {
$id=$row['id'];
$menu_top=$row['menu_name'];
$menu_url=$row['menu_url'];

print "<li><a href='$menu_url'>$menu_top</a>";

$sql_sub = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE sub_menu = '$menu_url' ";
$result_sub = mysql_query($sql_sub);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_sub);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sub))
 {
$id=$row['id'];
$menu_sub=$row['menu_name'];
$sub_url=$row['menu_url'];
If ($num_rows != 0)
{
print "<ul class='sub_menu'>
            <li><a href='$sub_url'>$menu_sub</a></li>
       </ul>";
}
}
print "</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the main_menu field, since you could just have anything that has a sub_menu field that is blank to be part of the main menu.

Comment: Can you list the fields in your db table and include some sample rows?

Comment: the link DB Fields  in the main post leads to a screenshot of my db fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for this would be something like the following (This will need to be changed for whatever way you interact with the database etc.):

```
// Here we do a query to get all the rows from the table
$db_result = db_execute_query('SELECT * FROM `menu_table` ORDER BY `order_no`');

// Here we take the rows and put it into a structured array
$items = array();
$hierarchy = array('' => array());
while ($row = db_fetch_row($db_result)) {
    $items[$row['menu_name']] = $row['menu_name_en'];
    if ($row['main_menu'] == 'yes') {
        $hierarchy[''][] = $row['menu_name'];
    } else {
        if (!isset($hierarchy[$row['sub_menu']]) {
            $hierarchy[$row['sub_menu']] = array();
        }
        $hierarchy[$row['sub_menu']][] = $row['menu_name'];
    }
}

// Here we define a recursive function to run through our $hierarchy array;
function show_menu($name = '') {
    if (isset($hierarchy[$name])) {
        if ($name == '') {
                echo '<ul class="dropdown">';
        } else {
                echo '<ul class="sub_menu">';
        }

        foreach ($hierarchy[$name] as $sub) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">' . $items[$sub] . '</a>';
            show_menu($sub);
            echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

// Here we execute the recursive function on the main menu
show_menu('');
```

Try to understand what I'm doing here instead of just implementing it verbatim. Once you get to know recursive functions, a whole new world can open for you.

Also note that your db table could be changed to make this code simpler

Comment: thanks. It will take me some time to discover this new world. For now I implemented it with just a nested query, but will definitely test your suggestion and understand the flow in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think these link will help you out. if not please let me know i will give you the code

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10337808-how-to-create-menu-submenu-subsubmenu-using-php-mysql

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?718237-how-to-create-dynamic-menu-and-submenu-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: I looked at the links you sent me... But I am kind of lost... I guess I can always do it with two separate queries, but will be nice if I can put some logic behind. Your help is highly appreciated